# What is this regex doing? match = /^plus_([0-9]+)$/.match(m.to_s)

Tags: ruby, regex

What is this RUBY regex doing:

```
match = /^plus_([0-9]+)$/.match(m.to_s)
```

It seems to be matching 'plus_' and then a number.

But what is the `.match(m.to_s)` part doing?  is it chaining to itself? I don't understand.

**Sorry its Ruby.**

Answer (score 2):

[Calling `.match(s)` on a regex runs the regex against `s` and returns a `MatchData` object](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001205). `m.to_s` simply means "call the `to_s` method of `m`" (i.e. convert it to a string).

Comment: yes, the OP said that in the question. He's asking bout the .match bit

Comment: @Paul: Yes, my bad. Replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, nice edit! I thought it was Ruby to begin with - my answer still holds.

You are correct about what the regex matches. However, `.match()` is the method used to match the regex against strings. It returns a MatchData object which you can then use to find out information about the match.

So `/^plus_([0-9]+)$/` creates a regex object, `.match(m.to_s)` matches it against m as a string, and the resulting MatchData is stored in match.

See [the Regexp documenation](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Regexp.html#M001578).

Answer (score 0):

I've never looked at ruby, but based on what others have said here, this seems to be calling the "match" method of the regex that was just defined, against the string "m".

So the regex itself becomes an "object", to which the method "match" is called, and the argument is the result of (m.to_s), which is just a string.  The result of the "match()" method is then returned into a variable named "match".

I think the fact that the method call is the same name as the return variable is what's making this seem weird.

Now this could be 100% wrong, as I've NEVER looked at ruby, but based on what others have said, this is what it looks like.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote this. I don't think answers should be written A) based solely off interpretation of others' answers to the question and B) without having any experience with the environment for which the question is being asked. An answer with "this could be 100% wrong" just strikes me as a bit off.

Comment: Prior to delnan editing his answer, everybody here was dancing around something that seemed obvious if you just look at what people were saying about it.  You're basically downvoting me for sound analysis.  Thanks a lot.  You probably would have up-voted me if I had NOT put qualifiers on it.  That makes so much sense.

Comment: @Kevin: I used to have a downvote for my irrelevant answer - rightfully so. (I didn't downvote, but I can understand what Rob is complaining about)

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry if I came off as abrasive, it wasn't my intention; I wasn't trying to offend or stir up an argument. I feel like the qualifying statement at the end of your answer was my primary reason for the downvote. If you remove it, I'll rescind my vote.

Comment: @Rob - See, IMO I'd rather have guesses STATED as guesses, rather than people commenting with little/no experience, and stating as expert opinion.  I don't even throw out guesses usually, but this time seemed OK to do so because no "real" answer was there as of the time of my posting.  But I'll remove the final line if it makes you happy.

Comment: @Kevin - A valid point. I understand where you're coming from and I've changed my opinion; thanks for providing your comments. Given your last comment, I feel like you shouldn't remove your last sentence simply based on my asshattery. I've reverted your edit and removed my downvote.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks man.  I'm glad we had the discussion, as I didn't know people held such opinions anyways, though it makes sense in hindsight.  Glad to have it with someone reasonable like you.  It's all good.